# Evaluating $\frac{d}{dx}\int_3^{x^2}e^{t^3}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, gamma-function

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_3^{x^2}e^{t^3}dt$

I suppose I don't fully understand the notation used within this problem.

Using the second fundamental theorem of calculus: $\int_a^b f(x)dx = F(x)\bigr|_a^b = F(b)-F(a)$ I am able to evaluate a definite integral, however, I don't understand how $x^2$ can be applied to a function $f(x)=e^{t^3}$.

The function doesn't have any values of x, so far as I can tell.

A further point of confusion, were the function to be: $f(x)=e^{x^3}$, it would evaluate to [this](http://tinyurl.com/pq8d9po).

I don't recall reviewing any material on the $\Gamma$ function, and really have no understanding of it.

I'm not exactly sure what to make of this problem.

Comment: You don't need to integrate it first. Google newton leibnitz theorem

Comment: We want the derivative of $F(x^2)-F(3)$. Use the Chain Rule.

Comment: First thing: can you find $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x h(t)\,dt$ if I **don't** tell you what the function $h$ is?

Comment: Similar problems have been discussed (often) on this site: a recent example is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779924/how-do-i-find-the-derivative-given-this-weird-integral

Comment: @David No. I don't understand how $x$ relates to $t$ within $h$. The set-up of the problem appears a bit foreign to me.

Comment: Try the link posted by @RecklessReckoner then.

Comment: @David Still not really making the connection of the numbers $t$ and $x$.

Comment: What answers do you get for the question in my first comment if (a) $h(t)=t^2$; (b) $h(t)=8t^3$; (c) $h(t)=\sin t$; (d) $h(t)=e^{4t}$; (e) $h(t)=\cos4t$?  What do you notice?  Can you explain it?

Comment: $ \ t \ $ is a so-called "dummy variable" for the purpose of using something other than $ \ x \ $ in writing the integral itself.  It will take on the values $ \ t \ = \ 3 \ $ and $ \ t \ = \ x^2 \ $ at the endpoints of the interval, and all values in between for the integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $\int_a^b f(x)dx = F(x)\bigr|_a^b = F(b)-F(a)$.

Applied to your problem, this reads as $\int_3^{x^2}e^{t^3}dt=F(t)\bigr|_{t=0}^{t=x^2}=F(x^2)-F(3)$, where $F$ is a fairly complicated function such that $\frac {dF(t)}{dt}=f(t)=e^{t^3}$.

Take the derivative, $\frac {d}{dx}(F(x^2)-F(3))=\frac{dF(x^2)}{dx}=\frac{d(x^2)}{dx}.\frac{dF(x^2)}{d(x^2)}=2x.f(x^2)=2x.e^{(x^2)^3}$.

Comment: Where does the 2x appear from? I'm not entirely understanding your answer. Apparently, $\frac{dF}{dx}=(\frac{d}{dx}\int_3^{x^2}e^{t^3}dt)$ which I evaluated to be $e^{(x^2)^3}$

Comment: Quite obviously, $2x$ is $\frac{d(x^2)}{dx}$. You are deriving $F(x^2)$, not $F(x)$. Read about the chain rule, as several others mentioned.

Comment: So, apply the chain rule to problem then, I suppose?

Comment: The complete solution is in front of your eyes, chain rule inclusive.